# JWT nuget package cannot be restored

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget

I have dotnet core installed on CentOS, and a project that is using JWT

https://www.nuget.org/packages/JWT/3.1.1

Locally on my OSX the restore works perfectly well:

```
dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.3)

Product Information:
Version:            2.0.3
Commit SHA-1 hash:  eb1d5ee318

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Mac OS X
OS Version:  10.13
OS Platform: Darwin
RID:         osx.10.12-x64
Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

Version  : 2.0.3
Build    : a9190d4a75f4a982ae4b4fa8d1a24526566c69df
```

Server:

```
dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.3)

Product Information:
Version:            2.0.3
Commit SHA-1 hash:  c85173f757

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     centos
OS Version:  7
OS Platform: Linux
RID:         centos.7-x64
Base Path:   /opt/rh/rh-dotnet20/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

Version  : 2.0.3
Build    : N/A
```

But on the server it doesn't work:

```
dotnet add package JWT --version 3.1.1
Writing /tmp/tmphdc0Ux.tmp
error: Unable to load the service index for source 
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception.
error:   The type initializer for 'Http' threw an exception.
error:   The type initializer for 'HttpInitializer' threw an exception.
error:   Unable to load DLL 'System.Net.Http.Native': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found.
error:    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

dotnet installation commands:

```
yum install centos-release-dotnet
yum install rh-dotnet20
```

I tried dotnet clean, and tried to change package version to newer or older, nothing works. Other packages in my .csproj are restored successfully, any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: I spun up an image of CentOS7 and had no issues [sample output](https://pastebin.com/UidAc4YV).  The error you are receiving seems to be due to an incomplete and/or corrupt installation of the dotnet SDK.  How did you install it?  If you installed from the Microsoft product feed then what output do you get from `yum list installed | grep microsoft`?

Comment: @Pace , thanks for the comment, I edited the question to put in how I installed dotnet. ```yum list installed | grep microsoft``` returns nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens when some native prerequisites of .NET Core aren't met. In this case, `libcurl` either doesn't exist or an incompatible version is installed

Consult the [Prerequisites for .NET Core on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites) document and make sure you use the latest versions (currently .NET Core Sdk 2.1.4 where you have been using 2.0.3)

Comment: other packages are being installed, all packages in my csproj are fine except this

Comment: Many packages (e.g. System.YYY) come built into the dotnet runtime and thus don't actually require installation from the Internet.  Is it possible this is the first remote package?

Comment: I just checked again, all prerequisites, this is the only one that wasn't installed: ```lttng-ust``` installed it, to no avail.  This is a packages that is used ```Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql``` for mysql and it installs, another for swagger ```Swashbuckle.AspNetCore``` also install properly

Comment: @Pace & Martin, it was actually as proposed by Pace, the way I installed dotnet isn't good, I followed the instructions on Martin's url and now it worked fine.